# How do you change the colour of tags?

Tags: ios, iwork

In the new update of Pages, Numbers and Keynote for iOS 11 and in Files you can now add tags. Is there a way to change the colour of tags once you’ve added them?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, on iPad you just hold the document until the options line pops up (copy, rename, move etc.) - the second last on the right should say tags.

Comment: I mean once you’ve added the tag I can’t figure out how to change the colour. I know how to change the tags of a document and rename tags but I don’t know how to change the colour of a tag.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. You can rename them in the files app, but I don’t think you can change color of an already set tag. At least not on iOS. If you have mac, you can change it very easily. (They should all sync.)